# Iterating over files containing certain string and putting that string in a new file

Tags: bash, shell, scripting

I have files that contain two lines always staring with `foo` and `bar` followed by a colon, a space and a fixed length string (can contain uppercase letters `A-Z`, numbers `0-9` and `<`):

```
foo: PF29273467<<<<<<<<
bar: CLPERJD<<<<<122111
```

I want to iterate over each file, concatenate the strings from `foo` and `bar` and append this new string as a new line in a text file, preceded by the filename from the file of the string's origin and a space.

So when iterating over a set of 3 files (file1.x, file2.x, file3.x), the new textfile's content would be:

```
file1.x PF29273467<<<<<<<<CLPERJD<<<<<122111
file2.x FLOEH73443<<<<1<<<CROEKJF<<<<<1F2122
file3.x IRHDS72455<<<<23<<XXXSDWR<<<<<122111
```

I'm not too familiar with bash scripting, so until now all I could come up with is this iterating over the files and printing the line that contains `foo:`
    #!/bin/bash

```
for f in *.x; do
 if grep -q foo: "$f"; then
   cat $f | grep foo:
 fi
done
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `perl` `regEx`, I was able to achieve this.

```
#!/bin/bash

for file in *.x
do
   fooOP=$(perl -lne 'print "$1" if/^foo:\s(.*)$/' "$file")
   barOP=$(perl -lne 'print "$1" if/^bar:\s(.*)$/' "$file")   
   printf "%s %s%s\n" "$file" "$fooOP" "$barOP"
done > newfile
```

On seeing the output file

```
$ cat newfile
file1.x PF29273467<<<<<<<<CLPERJD<<<<<122111
file2.x FLOEH73443<<<<1<<<CROEKJF<<<<<1F2122
file3.x IRHDS72455<<<<23<<XXXSDWR<<<<<122111
```

A better optimisation could be done over the `perl` `regEx` to have it as a single capture.